# How Can I Use the Max Function to Filter a List and Insert Into

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to do something like:

```
Insert Into (col1, col2, col3)
Select col1, col2, col3, max(col4)
From mytable
Group By col1, col2, col3
```

That gives me: `The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list.`

I want to use the max function to filter out dupes but when I select this extra field, the order of fields and number of fields doesn’t match up.  How can I filter a list from a table, use the max function, and insert all records except the ones in the max field?

Comment: Insert into have 3 columns,
Your select query returns 4 columns.
Insert column list and select column list should match the number of columns

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what *you* mean by dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use the max function to filter out dupes

Well, I suspect that you actually want `distinct`:

```
insert into my_target_table(col1, col2, col3)
select distinct col1, col2, col3 from my_source_table
```

This will insert one record in the target table for each distinct `(col1, col2, col3)` tuple in the source table.

Comment: Oh my!  I was so focused on something totally unrelated, I totally forgot about that.  Thanks for helping me get back to reality.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing something like this:

```
Insert Into (col1, col2, col3)
    select col1, col2, col3
    from mytable
    where t.col4 = (select max(t2.col4)
                    from mytable t2
                    where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col3 = t.col3
                   );
```

However, this is pretty much equivalent to `select distinct` (`NULL` values might be treated differently).  You probably want dupes defined on only one column, so I'm thinking:

```
insert into (col1, col2, col3)
    select col1, col2, col3
    from mytable
    where t.col4 = (select max(t2.col4)
                    from mytable t2
                    where t2.col1 = t.col1
                   );
```